# Invariant ergodic measure Volterra operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Define the Volterra operator $V$ on $C_0([0,1])\triangleq \{g \in C([0,1]):g(0)=0\}$ by
$$
f \mapsto \int_0^{\cdot} f(s)ds.
$$
Is there an example of an ergodic and $V$-invariant Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $C_0([0,1])$?

Comment: Do you really mean a probability measure on $C_0([0,1])$? Or do you rather mean a probability measure on $(0,1]$ which is invariant under the dual operator $V^*$?

Comment: A probably measure on this path space,  such as the Wiener measure (if it were to satisfy these assumptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the delta measure on the identically 0 function (and this is the only one).

Comment: If I instead consider the space $C([0,1])$ and look for locally-positive probability measures, are there other functions?  Here is the formal follow-up question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345943/invariant-ergodic-measure-volterra-operator-on-continuous-functions